# Fulltext search together with spatial query

Tags: geospatial, geo, spatial-query

We have some geographic data, you can think them as the places or geonames.

We have almost six hundred thousands of records, each record have the following fields:

```
id name lng lat  ....
```

Now we want to search according to this fields and support the fuzzy search , but use the `like` by database is not a good idea.

So we tried `Lucene` to do the fulltext search, this works well for the `name` field query, but it I have no idea when query and mix the `name` field and `lng` `lat` fields together.

For example, the user may want to query the places contains keywords "xxx" around a certain point with lat:30,lng 40 with distance 100 meter.

This is a kind of geographic query, which I think it is better to query by the spatial db like postgis or something else,but how about the `name field?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: We now use access, but we plan to postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HGUser, **PostgreSQL** and **SQL Server** (2008 onwards - 2012 is best) are both great options that meet your requirements.  Both support **FULL TEXT** searching and **Spatial** Queries with **Indexing** (either as singular or combined WHERE clauses).

Just make sure to construct a geography / geometry object from your lat / long coordinates to benefit from the Spatial indexing.

### For PostgreSQL

You can read about Geography / Geometry within the User Manual at

http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/pdf/9.3/postgresql-9.3-A4.pdf (section 8.8)

And Full Text will be found at Chapter 12 of the same document.

### For SQL Server

You can read about Geography / Geometry at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848797.aspx

And full text indexes at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: How about the FULL TEXT with PostgreSQL compared with lucene?

Comment: @hguser Honestly, I don't know enough about lucene to offer good advice.  My preference has long been towards SQL Server, but PostgreSQL has a proven fast and elegant Spatial model which should not be discounted.

Comment: Fine, I will have a try with postgresql, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,
you have many options without touching full blown spatial DBMS.
I would actually look into:

- lucene spatial
  https://www.openshift.com/blogs/free-text-and-spatial-search-with-spatial4j-and-lucene-spatial
- SolR
  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search
- ElasticSearch
  www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/spatial-search-tutorial.html

Regards,
Simone.